# Function return value in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, variables

I have written a function using matlab as follows.

```
function xout= testfunc(b)
xout = b;
end
```

I executed this function by giving an value for b as follows.

```
addpath ('C:\Users\vish\docs\copy');% this is the place of the file location
testfunc(5);
```

This gives me a variable in my work space ans which is equal to 5,which is the general variable once after all functions are evoked.But the problem is,even though the function is executed properly, when try to use the variable xout it gives the following error message.

```
addpath ('C:\Users\vish\docs\copy');
testfunc(5);
varout
```

**Undefined function or variable 'varout'.**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is varout? I didn't see you define varout anywhere... So that's why Matlab complains it's undefined. Or do you mean xout?

Comment: I also think he/she means `xout` as it is mentioned in the textual description above. `xout` is only locally defined within your function `testfunc`. You can name these variables whatever you like they are (in general) not visible outside your function. Therefore you'd have to call it like `xout = testfunc(5)` (if you want to use the same variable name, which is possible).

Comment: Assume you mean `xout`. The variable goes out of scope at the end of the function. The return value is copied to `v = testfunc(5);` or to `ans`. You may want to read the [Matlab primers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf). Even experienced programmers starting with Matlab should read this.

Comment: @MatthiasW. I am not sure since Matlabs implementation of return values is not that discussed, but the guess is that it is not only invisible, but not even defined outside of the function. The variable should go out of scope and the memory not even be accessible to you program anymore.

Comment: @patrik: Yes you are right, "out of scope" is the correct term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if you do not assign a function returned value to a variable, Matlab assigns it to `ans` (as you already experienced). By calling

`testfunc(5)`

Matlab will create a variable in the workspace called `ans` with value `5`.

Also the name `xout` is the output variable name in the body of your function (i.e. in the `testfunc` script the output variable name is known as `xout`) but when you call such function you can assign its output to any variable (i.e. with the name you prefer).

`myNewOutput=testfunc(5)`

and `myNewOutput` in the workspace will have value `5`. Or you can as well use the same name you used in the function, is up to you:

`xout=testfunc(5)`

and `xout` will have value `5` as well.

Comment: Thanks every one.Great help.